# Continue button on one page checkout does not move to next step (step 2 to step 3) in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2. When I click on "ship to this address" at one page checkout then Continue botton is not working. Its only highlights the next step (Shipping Information) but not opening or skips that step. Before some days it was working fine. Can anyone help me to sort out the same...

Comment: Is this issue got solved??

Answer (score 0):

Three questions from my side.

```
1. Are you working in your local machine?
2. Did u enabled HTTPS in the admin panel?
3. Have u given secure url as HTTPS?
```

Then this problem may occur. Because, earlier I faced this issue. First disable the https in the admin panel and remove the https in secure url field and place http. This happens when the url changes from http to https. THis change of url is happens when we move to the payment information tab. In local if u didn't install SSL certificates, then u cant use https in your local machine. If you want to use https in your local machine also, then u have to install SSL certificates locally. After all the above changes, restart the server and try now. Come back to me if it works or didnt works.

Comment: I am working online and I dont have SSL certificate so I didnt enabled  HTTPS. I have given secure url as HTTP not HTTPS.